# Debug logs for Change Set Validation

Tags: validation, change-set, debug

I can't seem to get debug logs working for Change Set Validation in PROD. I have checked in the regular Debug Logs section and the Developer Console. They don't show up. The debug logs show up for everything else and I have the User Trace Flag levels FINEST for everything. Is there something I'm missing?

I have done research with the following links with no luck:

How to view the detailed debug log of the change set validation in production

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jcv1AAA

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_setting_debug_log_levels.htm&language=en

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this comment by Don Friedricksen on the idea [View debug log info for change set validation/deployment](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jcv1AAA)

> I found that setting a debug log for "Automated Processes" and then running a validation on a change set DOES yield debug logs!  Many of them - and change sets can be large.  So the max debug log size is exceeded almost every time.  Automated Processes debug logging can be a start - but it would be REALLY nice to have something configurable for change set debugging.

I tried, but my Apex logs when the validation progress was running showed up with the "EncryptableFieldUpserter" as the Operation under the user who initiated the validation.

[image]